# Disabling an iframe in a spoiler

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've got a question concerning html, especially iframes. English is not my native language and I'm kinda bad at html, so please have mercy (:

So: I have a spoiler using this tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function spoiler() {
        var st = document.getElementById('spoiler').style;
        st.display = (st.display == 'none' || st.display == '') ? 'block' : 'none';
      }
    </script>
<input value="OPEN" onclick="spoiler();" type="button" /> 
    <p id="spoiler" style="display:none;">
            IFRAME
    </p>
```

The iframe is a chatbox, so I want to disable the iframe while the spoiler is closed so you don't have to hear the sound all the time while not being in the chatbox. Does anyone know a possibility?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hiding it in the Dom via `style.display = 'none'` will hide it, but if a sound is launch it will be played.

I advise you to remove it from the `dom` and to add it if needed:
[Removing a child node in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp)

To add it you will have to create the iframe and add it to the DOM

```
var list=document.getElementById("myList");
list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
```

To create an element you will need  `CreateElement` and add it to the `DOM` with `AppendChild`

```
var node=document.getElementById("myList2").lastChild;
document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(node);
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)